# Dell T7400 won't boot Ubuntu unless the live USB is connected

Tags: boot, usb, dell

Ubuntu server 14.04

I have a Dell Precision T7400 with onboard SAS controller.  After installing Ubuntu from LinuxLive USB USB drive, the machine freezes at the boot screen.  I don't get any splash screens; this is happening well before that.  There is no drive activity at all.

The weird thing is that if I leave the USB key in the USB port, it all boots up fine, and I get to my Ubuntu prompt with no problems.  The BIOS boot order is the USB first and the local drive second.  I have not configured any RAID with the SAS controller.

I had Oracle Enterprise Linux installed (6.4) and it works no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It was a very simple error - GRUB was on the USB. It was a very simple fix; I just had to boot as normal with the USB connected and then run this command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

(on my machine, sdb was the install target drive)

It's all working nicely now

See this post on Super User for more details [Ubuntu Server installed from USB puts GRUB on the USB drive instead of the hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/176050/ubuntu-server-installed-from-usb-puts-grub-on-the-usb-drive-instead-of-the-hard).